# Opening file in C.How to prevent reading wrong data type

Tags: c, file

I am writing a code which reads decimal numbers from a .txt file and converts them to U2 notation.I need to secure the code in case of some random text in a file and I don't know how to do that.If there is a text instead of decimal number in my .txt then I need to show some error and stop the program.
Here is the function that opens the file:

```
//Opening file
int openFile(long arr[]) {

    FILE *f = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

    //if something went wrong with opening our file
    if(f == NULL) {
        perror("File could not be opened.");
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;  //for navigation around our array into which we
                //save numbers from opened file
    while(!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%d", &arr[i]); //loading numbers from file
        toU2(arr[i]);             //calling out function which converts numbers to U2
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);                      //closing file
}
```

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: [fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) _returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned_

Comment: Why don't use the number of fields correctly read by `fscanf`?

Comment: `%d` is not good for _decimal number_..... Maybe you want to write integer?

Comment: What is wrong with using **%d** for decimal number?I don't see any other way of reading signed integer with **fscanf** function.

Comment: [Decimal number](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_21.htm) means floating point, then `%f`

Comment: Is there only 1 number per line?

Comment: @LPs. `%d` means **decimal** (base-10) integer as opposed to he`%x`adecimal for example. And that introduction is wrong, there are no "decimal" floating point numbers in C standard - they're in *binary* (and yes, this distinction matters!)

Comment: LPs and Antti Haapala thanks for explaining that to me, I will keep it in mind :). @chux yes, there is only 1 number per line.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer to this question was actually pretty easy, thanks for help guys!
Here's the code for possible future travelers:

```
//Opening file
int openFile(long arr[]) {

FILE *f = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

//if something went wrong with opening our file
if(f == NULL) {
    perror("File could not be opened.");
    return;
}
int i = 0;  //for navigation around our array into which we
            //save numbers from opened file
int x = 0;
while(!feof(f)) {
    if(fscanf(f, "%d", &arr[i])){ //loading numbers from file
        toU2(arr[i]);             //calling out function which converts numbers to U2
    } else {                      //if loaded data was not an integer
        printf("Error");
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
fclose(f);                      //closing file
```

}